# Company Twitter comes up in the wrong language

Tags: seo, twitter

If you search "(company name) twitter", our twitter page doesn't come up at all.

If you search "(company twitter handle)", our twitter is the first result...but it's the bulgarian language version of the page.

I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Can you share your company name?

Comment: Is this the page? https://twitter.com/classic_truckin?lang=bg Check your settings inside Twitter, specifically your geo/language settings. Go through all settings just in case. The other possibility is, you signed up through a Bulgarian Twitter homepage somehow. (This is not a website issue - I checked your site, your language settings are fine, and anyway that wouldn't impact Twitter itself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I search for "Classic Truck Insurance Twitter", your classic_truckin page shows up, but it shows up as lang=bg as you suggest.

I agree with HenryVisotski. I think it's possible that your Twitter profile language settings could be messed up. It's also possible that you have inbound links pointing to your Twitter account that are coming from Bulgarian accounts or websites, which is causing Google to think that your business is primarily Bulgarian.

The more you start getting a following with English speaking customers, the more likely it will be that you start ranking your Twitter account in English and not in Bulgarian.

If for instance you have a few shares or comments from people who speak Bulgarian, but not a whole lot from English countries, Google will immediately see this as a signal that your Twitter account should be displayed in Bulgarian.

The best way to unconfuse Googlebot is to show it stronger English signals. This means inbound links pointing to your Twitter account from webpages that are in English. The higher their page authority the better. It also means getting a following going on Twitter from English based users.

You clearly have a little bit of action going on your Twitter account in English, but perhaps once you start getting even more your Google result should change.

Comment: Twitter location is set to US, language to English. I used Moz tools to look for backlinks and couldn't find any. 

We have a ton of bots in our followers, some of whom seem European in origin. I've been reluctant to purge them just because our followers are already low, but maybe that's what's causing this issue.